# Событие клика по checkbox?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Есть такой код:

```
$(document).on("click", "input", function (e) {
        console.log('kk');
    });
```

И элементы input. Эти элементы подгружаются на странице аяксом. Как ни пробовал, событие клика не срабатывает на них. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/uygLny3y/) реализации вашего кода с динамическим добавлением чекбоксов, всё работает.

```
// Функция добавления чекбокса
function addCheckbox() {
    $('#box').append('<input type="checkbox" />');
}

// Клик по кнопке добавления чекбокса
$('#addCheck').click(function() {
    addCheckbox();
});

// Ваша функция, но с алертом для наглядности
$(document).on("click", "input", function (e) {
        alert('kk');
    });
```

Comment: Другой скрипт перебивал...